# How to update data for bot

Tags: botframework

I have create a bot which tells release data for any movie. 
Should I be using conventional SQL DB to keep bot answers up to data?
I read about Document DB, is it good to try?

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion would be use some API if your data source has any. Like IMDB or some other source of data.
With that you will not have to manager database.
If you use DocumentDB or any other DB you have to make sure that data in that DB is upto date now for that you will reply on some API or web scraping. However you can directly do that in your bot itself.